# Get the term id from the url in views

Tags: views, blocks

I have a portfolio View. As we are expecting: The portfolio displays all the nodes of the content type of the portfolio in a grid. Based on the selected term of the tags above we can see the associated content in images and titles and some description.

I'm adding the view block of the portfolio in the Tags page (`taxonomy-term.tpl.php`) (so i can get the term from the url).

What I want to know is: How can I get the term from the url and then make the view get only the terms children of that term, so I can only see the portfolio of the selected terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about `Contextual filters`?

Comment: yes i do , and the problem solved ,add a new "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" contextual argument. From the section "When the filter value is NOT in the URL," choose "Provide default value "; then, select "Taxonomy term ID from URL."